# Subscribing to message and re-publishing only specific part, real time?

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am currently working on sending the information from /joint_states to an Arduino, however the information in my message is too large to be sent, even after increasing the buffer.

My plan is to make a program that subscribes to joint_states, scrapes the position array and re-publishes on a different topic. I am new to ROS so I have no idea where to start.

Could someone give me a helping hand? Thank you so much in advance :).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288749/subscribing-to-message-and-re-publishing-only-specific-part,-real-time?/) by [nyxaria](https://answers.ros.org/users/34658/nyxaria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might seem a bit redundant, but that's how I would do it.
(I'm assuming you want to keep everything except the position array)
1- Define a new message. I'm defining it in package `myPkg` and calling it `newMsg`.

```
Header header  
string[] name
float64[] velocity
float64[] effort
```

2- Write a node that on receiving a message (callback), publishes the data you want.

```
import rospy  
from myPkg.msg import newMsg  
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState  

def callback(msg):  
       out.header = msg.header  
       out.velocity = msg.velocity  
       out.effort = msg.effort  
       pub.publish(out) 


rospy.init_node('Scraper')  
sub = rospy.Subscriber('in', JointState, callback)  
pub = rospy.Publisher('out', newMsg)  
rospy.spin()
```

Note: If concerned about performance, implement this in the node you're subscribing to.

---

Originally posted by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) with karma: 249 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-17**:
+1 for the example. That is actually exactly what the `transform` node does / allows you, but without writing an actual node.

**Comment by [nyxaria](https://answers.ros.org/users/34658/nyxaria/) on 2018-04-19**:
Thank you, I ended up using your solution as the basis for mine :). Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is something you can use the `transform` node for in [topic_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools).

See #q261935 for a recent example.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nyxaria](https://answers.ros.org/users/34658/nyxaria/) on 2018-04-19**:
Hi, thank you for your response :). I have tried to do it using this way but only realised what I did wrong once I completed a working solution using @mohsen 's answer. (lack of understand how to construct MultiArrays :p.) Have a great day!